# Upgrading kubuntu to version 12.10 stops

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, dist-upgrade

It's on the step "Installing the upgrades", says it's "Configuring virtuoso-opensource-6.1", and the last line in the log is "Unpacking linux-headers-3.5.0-17 (from .../linux-headers-3.5.0-17_3.5.0-17.28_all.deb) ..."

.. And the application just sits there doing nothing. Trying to abort now says "The system could be in an unstable state if you cancel the upgrade", so I'd rather not do that :/

Any idea how I can kick the upgrade into gear again?

EDIT: I closed the program, ran dpkg -configure (which failed). Booted ran configure again,  some configuration, and things are up and running again. I'm leaving this open as I have no idea what the root cause was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/211975) question on launchpad.

The Virtuoso package seems to be unstable, as the upgrade sometimes fails and sometimes succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the upgrade going again by killing the virtuoso-t process from within Konsole by doing:
ps ax|grep virtuoso
sudo killall virtuoso-t

ps ax|grep virtuoso showed one process still running so I did:
sudo kill -9

Would like to know why this is happening.